# i want to check the date while the user enters dob in the signup form in grails

Tags: grails

I have a form in which user have to enter the date of birth in the format like year/mm/date .I want to check that the year will be between 1990 to 2050 , month not greater than 12 and date not greater that 31.I want this in grails.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work about what you tried? SO isn't a "write this code for me" service.

Comment: i am just testing [1990-2000]/[1-12]/[1-31] in http://www.regexr.com/  but it is not working.I want it in grails domain class under constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the domain class field is of type `String` the following constraint should meet your requirements

```
static constraints = {

    date validator: { dateAsString ->

        try {
            Date d = Date.parse('yyyy/MM/dd', dateAsString)
            d[Calendar.YEAR] in 1990..2050
        } catch (ex) {
            false
        }        
    }
}
```

While this approach will work, personally, I would make the domain class field a `Date` and use Grails' databinding support to convert the form's request parameter.